# Why Did Anko get so fat?

Tags: naruto

**Alert: This post contains spoilers. If you are not up-to-date to Naruto's manga, don't read it.**

> In the last chapter of Naruto, Anko appears as Chouchou's sensei:[image]

She was always in good shape during the entire series.

[image: Anko]

Is there a reason she got this fat? Is this some kind of a joke made by Masashi Kishimoto?

Comment: Food is addicting. Pies are also tasty.

Comment: Too much dango, most probably.

Comment: maybe she piled it on when she was pregnant and hasn't lost it all yet, though for that to be plausible we'd need a canon reference on her child

Comment: many years have passed and there's no war and mostly, women gain weight as they grow old. MOSTLY

Comment: human metabolism slows down as they get older

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

[Source - deviantart](http://i-am-a-mellow-drama.deviantart.com/art/Why-I-said-Anko-is-Fat-60424887)

This may be the reason... too many dangos.

As seen in the image above, during the Chunin Exam, Anko consumed four times the amount of calories an adult female needs in one day. If this is typical in her diet she would likely be unable to burn all those calories every day, which would lead to weight gain.

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. i have edited your question to add in the image but could you also expand on your own explanation incase if both the image and the site goes down?

Comment: Even if it is a poor answer, that clip from Shonen Jump is really helpful

Answer (score 3):

As a ninja I assume that you burn a lot more calories and fat much more easily and quickly than regular individuals. So Anko having a slim figure at the time despite eating like this is no big deal. However, when peace came along and she became an instructor I am guessing she spent a lot less time training and taking missions and more time eating therefor the weight began to pack on and she got fat.

Comment: It might not just be that she ate more, but that she ate the same amount and can no longer burn it off.

Comment: i think what you are trying to say is that as people age they tend to have a lower metabolism and thus burn less energy.